# Recordset count always returns -1

Tags: vba, excel, adodb, recordset

My code goes like this

```
rst.CursorLocation = adUseClient
Set rst = MySQLConn.Execute("SELECT * FROM " & viewName & ";")
MsgBox rst.RecordCount
```

i want to know the number of records in my record set but the record count always returns -1. how will i fix this?

Comment: The RecordCount can be applicable only for the MySqlDataReader retrieved when FetchAll property set to true.

Comment: My comments were actually not accurate since it's for Mysql. Check bwest's answer to use static cursor.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use a static cursor. To do this you need to explicitly create the RecordSet object, like so:

```
Set objRS = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
objRS.CursorLocation = adUseClient
objRS.Open "SELECT * FROM " & viewName & ";", objConn, adOpenStatic,adLockReadOnly, adCmdText
```

Implicitly created RecordSets have server-side cursors, which causes the -1 to be returned.

For more info: http://www.adopenstatic.com/faq/recordcounterror.asp

Comment: Hi,

 Set rst = New ADODB.Recordset
        rst.CursorLocation = adUseClient
        rst.Open "SELECT * FROM " & view, MySQLconnection, adOpenStatic, adLockReadOnly

however the recordcount still is -1

Comment: Hi bwest, can i do this one?

Set rst = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
        rst.CursorLocation = adUseClient
        rst.CursorType = adOpenStatic
        rst.LockType = adLockReadOnly
        Set rst = MySQLConn.Execute("SELECT * FROM " & viewName  & ";")

Comment: Good answer. Correct and concise. Perfect for looking up a syntax issue. Even though it is very old.